# Passing Parcelable Array from AppWidgetProvider to RemoteViewsService

Tags: android, android-intent, android-appwidget

I'm trying to pass some parcelable array to `RemoteViewsFactory` through `RemoteViewsService`. Inside my custom `AppWidgetProvider` I have smth like below:

```
Intent appWidgetIntent = new Intent(context, ReportRemoteViewsService.class);
appWidgetIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("list", list);
appWidgetIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);

RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget_report_layout);
rv.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.appwidget_report_listview, appWidgetIntent);
//dumpIntent(appWidgetIntent);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], rv);
```

`list` is an `ArrayList<CustomObject>` where `CustomObject implements Parcelable` (with `writeToParcel` and static `CREATOR`). I'm printing extras and there are both list and id, but when I print `Intent` inside `RemoteViewsFactory` there is only `appWidgetId`...

```
public class ReportRemoteViewsService extends RemoteViewsService {

    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent{
        //dumpIntent(intent);
        return new ReportRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
    }
}
```

same situation when I try to pass single parcelable (not array). why?!